# Bug in pandas.Series/DataFrame.fillna limit?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to fill a DataFrame and Series using `fillna` with the `value` and `limit` keywords. The `limit` is respected when not including `value`, but as soon as including `value` the limits are no longer respected. Here's an example using a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), index=['a', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'h'],columns=['one', 'two','three'])
df2 = df.reindex(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g','h','i', 'j','k'])

In [7]: df2
Out[7]:
        one       two     three
a -0.942695  0.465658 -0.966754
b       NaN       NaN       NaN
c -1.208036  0.287274 -1.116466
d       NaN       NaN       NaN
e  0.041212  0.065966 -1.895570
f  0.869104 -3.481962 -0.280699
g       NaN       NaN       NaN
h -1.151732 -0.310296 -1.701202
i       NaN       NaN       NaN
j       NaN       NaN       NaN
k       NaN       NaN       NaN

In [8]: df2.fillna(method='pad', limit=1)
Out[8]:
        one       two     three
a -0.942695  0.465658 -0.966754
b -0.942695  0.465658 -0.966754
c -1.208036  0.287274 -1.116466
d -1.208036  0.287274 -1.116466
e  0.041212  0.065966 -1.895570
f  0.869104 -3.481962 -0.280699
g  0.869104 -3.481962 -0.280699
h -1.151732 -0.310296 -1.701202
i -1.151732 -0.310296 -1.701202
j       NaN       NaN       NaN
k       NaN       NaN       NaN

In [9]: df2.fillna(value=999,method='pad', limit=1)
Out[9]:
          one         two       three
a   -0.942695    0.465658   -0.966754
b  999.000000  999.000000  999.000000
c   -1.208036    0.287274   -1.116466
d  999.000000  999.000000  999.000000
e    0.041212    0.065966   -1.895570
f    0.869104   -3.481962   -0.280699
g  999.000000  999.000000  999.000000
h   -1.151732   -0.310296   -1.701202
i  999.000000  999.000000  999.000000
j  999.000000  999.000000  999.000000
k  999.000000  999.000000  999.000000
```

Am I missing something here, or is this a bug?

Cheers

Edit: using pandas 0.8.1 on python 2.7 with numpy 1.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually by design. The `limit` keyword is designed to go with the `method` keyword because you have to specify the ordering (i.e., forward-fill or back-fill) and you don't have that with `value`.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Is there a way around this? I was actually trying to fill a timeseries using interpolation, but I don't want to fill too long segments so I need the limit somehow. Since there is no 'limit' in interpolation I tried via the fillna. I think it could be useful to allow for limits in the interpolation method, and also when filling custom values with fillna

Comment: I created a github issue to keep track of this. A limit keyword for interpolation makes sense. You're welcome to add any additional comments here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1892