# Pandas Dataframe a limit for fillna has not been implemented yet

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, fillna

I want to implement a `fillna` method over a pandas dataframes with the `method='bfill'` and a `limit`

```
df= df.fillna( method='bfill', limit=5)
```

but I have the following error

```
NotImplementedError: specifying a limit for fillna has not been implemented yet
```

I found in this discussion that a bug existed but I didn't find another answer since then.
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/1892

I used the keyword `method` but it still doesn't work
[Bug in pandas.Series/DataFrame.fillna limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372899/bug-in-pandas-series-dataframe-fillna-limit)

Thank you.

Best,

Comment: Possibly because you're on an older version. This works on `v0.22`. So, I'd recommend upgrading.

Comment: I upgrated my version I have a version pandas-0.22.0
But it doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: `df.bfill(limit=5)` also works for me.

Comment: exactly the same error as before NotImplementedError: specifying a limit for fillna has not been implemented yet

Comment: In that case... The problem is specific to your data which you haven't provided.

Comment: I really can't understand. It's tricky. When I use this with a fake data that I construct and that resemble to my original data, it work s but not in my data

Comment: That's why it'd be great if you could figure out what data is causing it. Use binary search!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163467/discussion-between-amy21-and-cs).

Comment: I'm a little busy, and won't be able to respond quickly. Please let me know when you've narrowed the problem down!

Comment: I am figuring out a little bit why. The data of the column where I want to use the fillna is categorical and not an object

Comment: Ah, that's extremely helpful. You could convert to string, perform the fill, and then convert to categorical.

Comment: Yes I had converted it to object than to category. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you that the columns with NaNs is an **object type** and not a **categorical type**.

Answer (score 1):

Please use bfill with axis=1 and limit=5:

```
labeled_features = labeled_features.bfill(axis=1, limit=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the "limit" parameter and I found that it is useful. Now we can fill the the 'nan' value in a particular column with desired values( I mean to say that satisfies the requirement). E.g If we have given 
missing value=100
unique=4

```
df.fillna("unique1", limit=10, inplace=True)
df.fillna("unique2", limit=30, inplace=True)
df.fillna("unique3", limit=25, inplace=True)
df.fillna("unique4", limit=35, inplace=True)
```

above the code helps to fill "nan" value with desired number of "unique" .

Answer (score -1):

```
labeled_features.failure = labeled_features.failure.fillna(method='bfill', limit=7)
```